# Updating variable from within event subscription in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to update a variable from within an event subscription. The variables had updated inside however it has not updated outside.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { pairwise, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'elephant-component',
  templateUrl: './elephant.component.html',
})
export class ElephantComponent  {

routedFromTraining: boolean = false;

constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.router.events
   .pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd), pairwise())
   .subscribe((event) => {
     if (event[0]['url'] == '/trainings') {
       this.routedFromTraining = true;
       // this.routedFromTraining is true
     }
   });
  // this.routedFromTraining is false
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on the line `if (event[0]['url'] == '/trainings') {` to verify that it gets hit? As indicated in the answer by noobs, it's entirely normal for `this.routedFromTraining` to be false on the last line of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is an **ASYNCHRONOUS OPERATION** and you are trying to observe the change synchronously!  You might have set it as `false` initially. If you want to check what value it gets from `subscribe()`, you'll have to check **after** the `subscribe()` call has **completed** asynchronously.  So do this instead:

```js
this.router.events
   .pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd), pairwise())
   .subscribe((event) => {
     if (event[0]['url'] == '/trainings') {
       this.routedFromTraining = true;
       // this.routedFromTraining is true
     }
    }, 
    (er) => console.log(err),
    () => console.log(this.routedFromTraining)   // this is an asynchronous operation so correct output will be displayed here
   );
  // this.routedFromTraining is false
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How do I update the variable which is defined at the beginning of the class (which is the bound to the view)?

Comment: @supergiraffe Your variable is getting updated with the value you get from `subscribe()`. To display some asynchronous value in the view do `{{ yourVariableName  | async }}` (In your case: `{{ routedFromTraining  | async }}`).  You can read more about `async pipe` [here](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).